# ripgrep type definition to skip tests

Tags: ripgrep

I would like to be able to run `rg -Ttests` instead of typing `rg -g'!tests/' -g '!test/' -g'!Tests/' -g '!Test/'` , is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

How about an environment variable?

```
 tests='-g!tests/ -g!test/ -g!Tests/ -g!Test/'
 rg $tests foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `-T` (or `-t`) for this, since `-t/-T` are for file types, and file types [don't actually apply to directories at all](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/blob/4858267f3b97fe2823d2ce104c1f90ec93eee8d7/ignore/src/types.rs#L502-L506). This probably could be documented better.

The `tests='...'` solution from @OhMyGoodness is a pretty good one. You could also define an alias:

```
alias rgT="rg -g '!tests/' -g '!test/' -g '!Tests/' -g '!Test/'"
```